# After create-project - update not working: "Nothing to install or update"

Tags: github, composer-php

I create new site with "composer create-project schoolphp/framework". But when project changes - "composer update" doesn't update it with message "nothing to install or update", but project must be update with new files! 
Full my action-logs:

1) I upload my project to github: https://github.com/schoolphp/framework . After upload to packagist.org .

2) Install my project to local-site: composer install schoolphp/framework

3) Change package on github and make commit & push:
[My changes on github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaI0u.jpg)

4) I make also "new release" on github. Update it on packagist.

5) Now I run composer update on my local project and see:
"nothing to install or update":

6) I try to do: delete composer.lock , change composer.json:

```
    "require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.0",
    "schoolphp/framework": "*",
    "schoolphp/library": "dev-master"
  },
```

But still "nothing to update". 
P.S. But update works to schoolphp/library, when I change and do the same (vendor require).

How can I update my project after create-project?

Comment: Extra screenshot with no update: http://i.stack.imgur.com/516DL.jpg

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Nop. Think so composer can`t do it...